# How to highlight search results with elasticui?

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, elasticui

I made a simple interface to display application logs using [elasticui](https://github.com/YousefED/ElasticUI), I'd like to highlight the results to show what was matching

I tried to add this in my controller:

```js
$scope.$watch('ejs', function(ejs) {
    if (ejs !== undefined) {
        ejs.Highlight(['msg']);
    };
});
```

but it does not work (the request payload don't include the highlight part)

how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ElasticUI](https://github.com/YousefED/ElasticUI) now supports highlighting

Answer (score 1):

Highlighting has not been added to ElasticUI yet, but it should be fairly trivial to add. If you look at [IndexController](https://github.com/YousefED/ElasticUI/blob/master/src/controllers/IndexController.ts) you see it sets the *agg*, *filter*, *query*, and *sort* properties of [ejs.Request](http://docs.fullscale.co/elasticjs/ejs.Request.html). What you want is also add support for the *highlight* property in a similar way to how ElasticUI handles the other ones.

I've also opened [an issue](https://github.com/YousefED/ElasticUI/issues/3) for this. It would be great if you could try and contribute it - otherwise I expect to look at it later on.

Comment: I can't seem to get the new directive to work. I pulled it straight from the github docs. Can you confirm this is working correctly?

Comment: Probably better to move this discussion to Github, but yes; I've tested @Mathieu 's contributions before merging it in. Send me a fiddle and I'll try to help